# How to serialize interface typed member

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I have a class that has a property that is defined as interface.
Users of my class can assign to this property any class implementation that implements the interface.
I want to be able to load this class state from a textual file on disk. Users should be able to manually modify the xml file, in order to control the application's operation.

If I try to serialize my class, it tells me I cannot serialize an interface.
I understand that the serializer has no knowledge about the structure of the property's class, knowing only that it implements an interface.

I would have expected it to call GetType on the member, and reflect into the structure of the actual class. Is there a way to achieve this?
Is there another way to implement my requirement?

**Edit**: Clarifying my intentions:
Lets say I have this class:

```
class Car
{
IEngine engine
}
class ElectricEngine : IEngine 
{
int batteryPrecentageLeft;
}
class InternalCombustionEngine : IEngine 
{
int gasLitersLeft;
}
```

and the class user has a class with

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.Engine = new ElectricEngine() {batteryPrecentageLeft= 70};
```

When I serialize the class myCar, I expect the the xml to resemble this:

```
<Car>
<Engine>
<ElectricEngine>
<batteryPrecentageLeft>70</batteryPrecentageLeft>
</ElectricEngine>
<Engine>
</Car>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Jens solution I have created a serializer that does what I need. Thanks Jen.
Here is the code:

```
public class RuntimeXmlSerializerAttribute : XmlIgnoreAttribute { }

public class RuntimeXmlSerializer
{
    private Type m_type;
    private XmlSerializer m_regularXmlSerializer;

    private const string k_FullClassNameAttributeName = "FullAssemblyQualifiedTypeName";

    public RuntimeXmlSerializer(Type i_subjectType)
    {
        this.m_type = i_subjectType;
        this.m_regularXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(this.m_type);
    }

    public void Serialize(object i_objectToSerialize, Stream i_streamToSerializeTo)
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        this.m_regularXmlSerializer.Serialize(sw, i_objectToSerialize);
        XDocument objectXml = XDocument.Parse(sw.ToString());
        sw.Dispose();
        SerializeExtra(i_objectToSerialize,objectXml);
        string res = objectXml.ToString();
        byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res);
        i_streamToSerializeTo.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
    }

    public object Deserialize(Stream i_streamToSerializeFrom)
    {
        string xmlContents = new StreamReader(i_streamToSerializeFrom).ReadToEnd();
        StringReader sr;
        sr = new StringReader(xmlContents);
        object res = this.m_regularXmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
        sr.Dispose();
        sr = new StringReader(xmlContents);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
        sr.Dispose();
        deserializeExtra(res, doc);
        return res;
    }

    private void deserializeExtra(object i_desirializedObject, XDocument i_xmlToDeserializeFrom)
    {
        IEnumerable propertiesToDeserialize = i_desirializedObject.GetType()
            .GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() ==
                    typeof(RuntimeXmlSerializerAttribute)) != null);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propertiesToDeserialize)
        {
            XElement propertyXml = i_xmlToDeserializeFrom.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(e =>
                e.Name == prop.Name);
            if (propertyXml == null) continue;
            XElement propertyValueXml = propertyXml.Descendants().FirstOrDefault();
            Type type = Type.GetType(propertyValueXml.Attribute(k_FullClassNameAttributeName).Value.ToString());
            XmlSerializer srl = new XmlSerializer(type);
            object deserializedObject = srl.Deserialize(propertyValueXml.CreateReader());
            prop.SetValue(i_desirializedObject, deserializedObject, null);
        }
    }

    private void SerializeExtra(object objectToSerialize, XDocument xmlToSerializeTo)
    {
        IEnumerable propertiesToSerialize =
            objectToSerialize.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p =>
                p.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(a =>
                    a.GetType() == typeof(RuntimeXmlSerializerAttribute)) != null);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propertiesToSerialize)
        {
            XElement serializedProperty = new XElement(prop.Name);
            serializedProperty.AddFirst(serializeObjectAtRuntime(prop.GetValue(objectToSerialize, null)));
            xmlToSerializeTo.Descendants().First().Add(serializedProperty); //TODO
        }
    }

    private XElement serializeObjectAtRuntime(object i_objectToSerialize)
    {
        Type t = i_objectToSerialize.GetType();
        XmlSerializer srl = new XmlSerializer(t);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        srl.Serialize(sw, i_objectToSerialize);
        XElement res = XElement.Parse(sw.ToString());
        sw.Dispose();
        XAttribute fullClassNameAttribute = new XAttribute(k_FullClassNameAttributeName, t.AssemblyQualifiedName);
        res.Add(fullClassNameAttribute);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can mark the property as do-not-include.

There is a deeper problem though: Serialization can only capture simple 'state', not behaviour. Your class is not of the serializable kind. What 'value' do you expect the property to have after deserialization? `null` is the only option.

The proper workaround would be to think about What should actually be save and use a DTO for that part.

---

The following model can be serialized:

```
public class BaseEngine { }

[XmlInclude(typeof(InternalCombustionEngine))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ElectricEngine))]
public class Car
{      
    public BaseEngine Engine { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would not want to mark it as do-not-include because I need it serialized :). You ask "_What 'value' do you expect the property to have after deserialization?_" - The same value that was before the serialization. (explained in my question)

Comment: "same value that was before the serialization" - And is the implementing instance also serialized?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Windows 8 IE 10 … accident.  Sorry, I'm trying to undo it.  If you edit the post I can change it .... Sorry.

Comment: OK, with IE10 you're excused :)

Comment: I was able to undo the downvote, but can't upvote as originally intended.  Sorry, my browser keeps locking up lately, and I've been having a ton of trouble with Win8.

Comment: added example to the question

Comment: "added example"- yes, that clears things up. Real code would have been better though.

Comment: itaysk - @JensGranlund has the basis of your answer.

Comment: @Henk, I appereciate your effort, but as I wrote in a response to Jens answer, I can't know what kind of classes that implement the interface the user will use. in example, Maybe the user has implemented a new kind of engine, that I don't know of when compiling the code (I need to declare it in the XmlInclude Attribute).

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you could use a base class instead of an interface and serialize that.

**Update**

I realized that using a base class was not really an option for you.

The best solution would probably be to do a workaround with a DTO like Henk Holterman stated.

But if you really want a solution for your question I think you would have to create your own custom serializer, but I would not recommend that because you would end up with a lot of bugs to sort out.

Here is a example for a custom serializer, keep in mind that this example will 
need some work to be use full in a real application.

At least two things has to be added for this to work for more than just an example:

1. Exception handling
2. Casting or converting the xml element value to correct type on the line `anyThingProperty.SetValue(obj, propertyElement.Value, null);`

```
[TestClass]
public class SerializableInterfaceTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string serialize = AnyThingSerializer.Serialize(
            new SerializableClass {Name = "test", Description = "test1", 
                AnyThing = new Animal {Name = "test", Color = "test1"}});
        Console.WriteLine(serialize);
        object obj = AnyThingSerializer.Deserialize(serialize);
    }
}

public sealed class SerializableClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [AnyThingSerializer]
    public object AnyThing { get; set; }
}

public static class AnyThingSerializer
{
    public static string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        serializer.Serialize(new StringWriter(stringBuilder), obj);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()));
        foreach (XElement xElement in SerializeAnyThing(obj))
        {
            doc.Descendants().First().Add(xElement);
        }
        return doc.ToString();
    }

    public static object Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        object obj = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
        DeserializeAnyThing(obj, doc.Descendants().OfType().First());
        return obj;
    }

    private static void DeserializeAnyThing(object obj, XElement element)
    {
        IEnumerable anyThingProperties = obj.GetType()
            .GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == 
                    typeof (AnyThingSerializerAttribute)) != null);
        foreach (PropertyInfo anyThingProperty in anyThingProperties)
        {
            XElement propertyElement = element.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(e => 
                e.Name == anyThingProperty.Name && e.Attribute("type") != null);
            if (propertyElement == null) continue;
            Type type = Type.GetType(propertyElement.Attribute("type").Value);
            if (IsSimpleType(type))
            {
                anyThingProperty.SetValue(obj, propertyElement.Value, null);
            }
            else
            {
                object childObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                DeserializeAnyThing(childObject, propertyElement);
                anyThingProperty.SetValue(obj, childObject, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List SerializeAnyThing(object obj)
    {
        var doc = new List();
        IEnumerable anyThingProperties = 
            obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => 
                p.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault(a => 
                    a.GetType() == typeof (AnyThingSerializerAttribute)) != null);
        foreach (PropertyInfo anyThingProperty in anyThingProperties)
        {
            doc.Add(CreateXml(anyThingProperty.Name, 
                anyThingProperty.GetValue(obj, null)));
        }
        return doc;
    }

    private static XElement CreateXml(string name, object obj)
    {
        var xElement = new XElement(name);
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        xElement.Add(new XAttribute("type", type.AssemblyQualifiedName));
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
        {
            object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
            if (IsSimpleType(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
            {
                xElement.Add(new XElement(propertyInfo.Name, value.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                xElement.Add(CreateXml(propertyInfo.Name, value));
            }
        }
        return xElement;
    }

    private static bool IsSimpleType(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof (string);
    }
}

public class AnyThingSerializerAttribute : XmlIgnoreAttribute
{
}
```

Comment: Basically I wanted to avoid using base class because interfaces seemed more right. Also, I don't know in advance what kind of concrete types the user might use. (I understand I need to declare those in XmlInclude). Can I avoid having to know in advance the types of classes the user might use?

Comment: @Henk, OK I think I understand the question now, yes that would imply using XmlInclude; this would make my suggestion kind of worthless.

Comment: @itaysk, I think that if you don't know anything about the class you want to serialize it will not be possible to serialize it. I will think about it some more and see if I can come up with a viable solution.

Comment: @JensGranlund, It's true that I don't know anything about the class I want to serialize. I thought that if the class implements ISerializable, it would be possible.

Comment: With `interface IEngine : ISerializable` it might work. But that's a different serializer.

Comment: @Jens, your code is what I need, but has several compile time errors when I try to use it as-is. Thanks a lot for the idea. I have implemented my own serializer based on your guidelines. Posted it as a separate answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ExtendedXmlSerializer](https://github.com/wojtpl2/ExtendedXmlSerializer). 
If you have a classes:

```
public interface IEngine
{
    string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Car
{
    public IEngine Engine {get;set;}
}


public class ElectricEngine : IEngine 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int batteryPrecentageLeft {get;set;}
}

public class InternalCombustionEngine : IEngine 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int gasLitersLeft  {get;set;}
}
```

and create instance of this class:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
myCar.Engine = new ElectricEngine() {batteryPrecentageLeft= 70, Name = "turbo diesel"};
```

You can serialize this object using ExtendedXmlSerializer:

```
ExtendedXmlSerializer serializer = new ExtendedXmlSerializer();
var xml = serializer.Serialize(myCar);
```

Output xml will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Car type="Program+Car">
    <Engine type="Program+ElectricEngine">
        <Name>turbo diesel</Name>
        <batteryPrecentageLeft>70</batteryPrecentageLeft>
    </Engine>
</Car>
```

You can install ExtendedXmlSerializer from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedXmlSerializer/) or run the following command:

```
Install-Package ExtendedXmlSerializer
```

Here is [online example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uWg8eu)